# What is the computational complexity of approximate quantum adders, in terms of big O notation?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

I have recently found papers on approximate quantum adders. However, the papers do not seem to mention the computational complexities of their algorithms. What are their complexities, in terms of big O notation?

https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.110403
https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/qmetro/4/1/article-p1.xml?language=en